# Make all sublists same length by prepending nan

Tags: python

How can I make all of my sublists the same length (the length of the longest sublist) by prepending np.nan's on each sublist?

```
import random
[list(range(0,random.randint(1,5))) for x in range(n)]
```

So if the output is:

> [[0, 1], [0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3]]

It should look like:

> [[nan,nan,nan,0, 1], [nan,nan,nan,nan,0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2,
>   3, 4], [nan,0, 1, 2, 3]]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Idlehands I've tried reversing first and then .extend() and then reverse again. But this doesn't work if the list is empty

Comment: You might be overthinking it... how is the list of sublists supposed to be generated? Is it actual data or is it created with the `nan` paddings from the beginning?

Comment: Saying 'everything' is not useful. Show us the actual code that you tried, which gives us either a starting point or a hint what we should not try.

Comment: @BramVanroy it's a joke, I wrote two comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, find the length of the longest sublist using `max()`. Then, for each sublist, use a slice assignment to replace the content of that list with the right number of `NaN`s followed by the original list.

```
import random, math

n = 5
lists = [list(range(0,random.randint(1,5))) for x in range(n)]

# get the maximum length
maxlen = len(max(lists, key=len))

# pad left of each sublist with NaN to make it as long as the longest
for sublist in lists:
    sublist[:] = [math.nan] * (maxlen - len(sublist)) + sublist
```

Comment: Accepting this one because it's just barely faster than @Torin May

Comment: It'll get a lot faster as your `n` goes up.

Answer (score 3):

```
import random
import numpy as np

n = 5
a = [list(range(0,random.randint(1,5))) for x in range(n)]
for c in a:
    while len(c) < n:
        c.insert(0, np.nan)
print(a)
```

> > > [[nan, nan, nan, nan, 0], [nan, nan, nan, nan, 0], [nan, nan, nan, 0, 1], [nan, nan, 0, 1, 2], [nan, nan, nan, 0, 1]]

This is an example of what I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most pythonic code but I think it does the trick:

```
longest_list_length = 0
for sublist in output:
  if len(sublist) > longest_list_length:
    longest_list_length = len(sublist)

for sublist in output:
  nans_to_prepend = ['nan'] * (longest_list_length - len(sublist))
  sublist = nans_to_prepend + sublist
```

Comment: replacing the value of `sublist` won't change the value in the original list.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is generating the `np.nan` padding during the random creation, this simple one liner will suffice:

```
[[np.nan]*(5-j) + list(range(j)) for j in (random.randint(1, 5) for x in range(5))]

# [[nan, 0, 1, 2, 3], 
#  [nan, nan, 0, 1, 2], 
#  [nan, nan, nan, 0, 1], 
#  [nan, 0, 1, 2, 3],
#  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

You can of course replace `5` with `n` and determine your max length.